# What algorithm does Copyscape use for text comparison?

Tags: algorithm, similarity

So I was looking for an algorithm to compare text contents, and I found this site called Copyscape that has this very handy tool used for comparing articles ([link](http://www.copyscape.com/compare.php)). It seems to do a good job in detecting the similarity value (by percentage) between 2 text documents. I want to know which algorithm do they use in that tool, or maybe something similar to it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how copyscape plagiarism works. But if you ask me to implement one.

I will start with - Define 'plagiarism'? content-1 and content-2 are nearly similar. Let us say >80% are same. i.e content-1 is taken 20% is changed to produce content-2.

Now, Let us try to solve: what will be cost (no.of changes) to convert content-1 to content-2? This is a well know problem in DP(dynamic programming world) as [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or [EDIT Distance](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-5-edit-distance/) problem. The standard problem talks about strings distance, but you can easily modify it for words instead of chars. Additionally, you may need to track all the changes @ line #, word position on both contents.

Now, the above problem will give you **Least no.of changes for conversion** of content-1 to content-2. With the total length of content-1, we can easily calculate the % of changes to go to content-2 from content-1. If it below a fixed threshold (say 20%) then declare the plagiarism. Also, with the auxiliary information on line#, word position on both contents - You can show the changes made.